# How do I change my button text onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery slideToggle that I am using to display and hide certain content. It always show an arrow pointing down, but if clicked and the text is shown, the arrow should be pointing up. Anyway to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("p").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<button>&#8595;</button>
<p>Wow!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about `$(SELECTOR).text()` ?

Comment: Get yourself "font-awesome" or "gyphicons" (or just two image files, but I'd recommend the first option). Create two classes ".arrow-up" and ".arrow-down". Then switch between the classes on button click.

Comment: 6 upvotes? hmmmm....

Comment: @asprin I think this question was asked 1000 times already on SO. It looks like someone is collecting internet points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

change the `html content` of button on `slideToggle()`.

**Html :**

```
<button id="up">&#8593;</button>
<p>Wow!</p>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
   var arrowId = $(this).attr('id');
   if (arrowId == 'up') {
     $("button").html('&#8595');
     $(this).attr('id','down');
     } else {
     $("button").html('&#8593');
     $(this).attr('id','up');
     }
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/64a6fafh/1/

Comment: You not added the Jquery in the fiddle..i updated your fiddle..https://jsfiddle.net/ku7cxewa/1/

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Comment: Using `$(this).attr('id')` would be worthy of a -1 alone, ***Please*** use `this.id` people! Also, You're toggling an ID? **Whoah**.

Comment: Well noted. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

As simple as that!

```js
var toggled = false;
$("button").click(function() {
  if (!toggled) {
    $(this).html("&#8593;");
    toggled = true;
  } else {
    $(this).html("&#8595;");
    toggled = false;
  }

  $("p").slideToggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  &#8595;
</button>
<p>
  Wow!
</p>
```

Comment: Could you please provide me with the full code? It doesn't work in my code, strangly enough

Comment: This is the full code. You just need to put this in your `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 3):

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('down up');

  });
});
```

```css
.down {
  background-image: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png");
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
}
.up {
  background-image: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_48px-128.png");
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="down"></button>
<p>Wow!</p>
```

Comment: Addition: You don't need to toggle two classes. You can also assume the button points down, adding the class e.g. `reversed` makes it point up. If you want to start it pointing up, give it that class at init, `toggleClass()` will still make it work as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.. :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
        $( this ).text('NewButtonText');
    });
});
```

Comment: What about the other way round?

Comment: My bad, morning coding.. Rino Raj's answer toggling a class on click is probably the best way to accomplish this!

Answer (score 2):

This solutions checks if the button has an arrow pointing 'UP', if it does, replaces it with 'DOWN', and vice versa.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            if ($(this).text() == 'up'){
                $(this).html('&#8595;')
            }else{
                $(this).html('up');
            }
            $("p").slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gogaa33d/

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("button").text('Button Clicked');` to change the text of your button onclick

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").slideToggle();
    $("button").text('Button Clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>&#8595;</button>
<p>Wow!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion based on [@Jorrex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36326445) above.

You can also use e.g. button's class instead of a variable:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('toggled')) {
    $(this).html("&#8593;");
  } else {
    $(this).html("&#8595;");
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
  $("p").slideToggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  &#8595;
</button>
<p>
  Wow!
</p>
```

This way it would be much easier if one needs more than one such button on the same page.

**Edit:** Even if you don't plan to use more than one such button on a page, it's still safer not to use a variable here, because *any other function* inside `$(document).ready(function(){` could possibly interfere with that variable -- and make you waste your time trying to figure out why "that strange things" (see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/a9b47vtd/1/)) are happening.
(While the error may seem obvious in that example, such errors become much harder to spot when your codebase grows.)

Comment: If you use a class, they use the class do do something with it. Now you add a useless class :)

Comment: @Martijn, what do you mean by "useless class"? Ok, maybe it would be better to use something like `data-toggled`, I don't know.
But anyway, my only point was: **don't use a variable** here,
because if you have some other code on that page it is possible that some other function would use that variable and thus interfere with button's behavior.

Comment: Consider the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/yu2u9pyw/ ,
which has 5 such buttons. Notice that this way one doesn't need 5 variables like `var toggled1, toggled2, ...` and a complicated function to handle this 5 variables -- I only replaced `$("p").slideToggle` with `$(this).siblings("p").slideToggle`.

Comment: @Martijn, and yes, you're absolutely right about using `innerHTML` -- it's really much nicer! ;)

Another example: https://jsfiddle.net/a9b47vtd/1/

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on [Jorrex's answer](http://#36326445). I'm a fan of making code short and readable. Simple logic should be simple code. IMO this next example is easier to read, especially if you have lots of code in your file.

Also, you can just as easily use plain Javascript for this, making it more lightweight.

```
var toggled = false;
$("button").click(function() {
    this.innerHTML = !toggled ? "&#8593;" : "&#8595;";

    toggled = !toggled; // flip the value
    $("p").slideToggle();
});
```